# Show data from two datasets in one chart in SSRS V 11.0.5058

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to show in a chart the data stored in two datasets. The datasets have the same columns and variables, but diferent time filters. I can not modify the query because it is defined in an application that uses SSRS for reporting. In that application i can only choose the variables i want to show and a time filter.
for instance, i want tho compare the energy consumption of a factory for every hour in two diferent days. ( Y axis: Value; X Axis: timeStamp -DateTime-; Series: VarName)
Now, i show them in two different charts, but i need to use only one.
I've tried to create a calculated column with the hour from the timestamp called idHour (`=hour(Fields!timeStamp.value`)) in each dataset and then use the lookUp function (`=lookUp(Fields!idHour.value,Fields!idHour.value,Fields!Value.value,"DataSet2")`), but it does not work.

SO,
 Why is not working the lookUp function?
It's possible to create a third dataset and just add the rows from the other two datasets?
thank you in advance

Comment: What doesn't work about the lookup? Have you tried putting the data from DS1 and the lookup into a tablix and seeing what comes out? If you can get the data into a tablix, you should be able to get it into a graph.

Comment: The problem is i can't see anything. When i use the lookup function the report in the application appears as a blank page, no error message, just a blank page. using only the data from one dataset the report appears. As far as i know, the function looks correct, but is not working, and i cant get why

Comment: That implies the lookup isn't working. What do you get when you bring out Fields!idHour.Value in your tablix? Does that give you a realistic value?

Comment: i get the correct values in that case, one column the datetime, other column thhe idHour and another 2 columns for the values

Comment: Can you provide sample data from each dataset? Have you tried putting two tables in a test report, one for each dataset, and verifying that the data can find a match between the two?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, i have been reallly busy, but now it seems that is a problem of the application and the developers and looking for a solution. thank you again